# How can i change icon color on dblclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change a font Awesome icon color using jQuery with dblclick(). Basically I want to change the color when a user double clicks on the icon but it gives me an error

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class ="contain">
        <div id ="pic">
            <img src ="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div id="desc">
            <div id="img-row">
                <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <p><!---- some text ---></p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
   $('.fa fa-heart-o').dblclick(css("color", "red"));
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, what is the error? That's probably pretty important for us to know.

Comment: It was giving me "JavaScript error" in an online editor console. But it's fixed now. I used span to enclosed the Font Awesome element and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide a handler function for dblclick event. inside the handler function you can use `this` to change the color of clicked element. something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
        $('.fa fa-heart-o').dblclick(function(){
            $(this).css("color", "red");
         });
    });
```

Comment: jinx, no jinxs backs

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't affect the icon, but when i switch it to lets say a paragraph, it works perfectly fine. How can i make the icon respond to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your dblClick is correct, however afterwards it is looking for a function call. You can learn more here https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

`$( ".fa fa-heart-o" ).dblclick(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red")
});`